# Mobile-friendly view breaks formatting

Tags: docusignapi

We are testing our Docusign API integration and noticed that a PDF we are using only looks good on desktop but not on mobile with the default "Mobile-Friendly" view. I am attaching the screenshot with the example of broken formatting (no word breaks) that happens in Chrome browser. I know we can use the disableResponsiveDocument attribute to turn off responsive signing for the envelope completely but ideally we would like to fix this formatting issue. Are there any tips on how the PDF document needs to be initially created/formatted to avoid issues like that in mobile-friendly mode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text shouldn't be running together like this if the document is uploading correctly. I would recommend creating a customer support case so that we can create a ticket with our engineering team. Here's a link to the customer support portal: https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US